# c++ learning the order of map entry

Tags: c++, dictionary

If I have a map with keys as strings. How can I know which string is in which place in the map? For example, 'cats' is the first entry and 'dogs' are the second entry. How will I know that dogs are the second entry in the map? Should I go through the map and search/check the order or is there any easier way?

Comment: The map is sorted, so the position of each element depends on the others and may change upon insertion. Buy Why do you need to know?

Comment: What does "second entry" mean for you? Is it "what order were they entered in", "where are they in memory"? The whole idea of maps is that you should be protected from needing to know.

Comment: Isn't the domain of a map just a set, which doesn't have any ordering?

Comment: @AliAlamiri An `std::map` has an ordering. But a user shouldn't care about it.

Comment: It looks like you want to use the `std::map` as a proxy for sorting a bunch of `std::string`s. Why not put them in a vector, sort it and then use its indices instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) the element, and then compute the [`distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) between the element and the map's [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin).  Since this is a `map`, the complexity of `distance` will be `O(n)` with the number of elements in the map.  I doubt you'd see much performance improvement versus simply looping the map and counting, but I'd prefer to not write such hand-written loops.

But this smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why would you need the position of an element in a map?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that anyway better, and here's two reasons for that:

a) std::map has a tree inside that, so initially leaves of tree don't have linear order, only a partial order (of course you can compare two keys, but you can't do that for a general binary tree - that's the reason for complication).

b) std::map has bidirectional iterator, so you can't have effective iterator arithmetics. You could do that like this:

```
typedef map<string, int> MyMapT;
MyMapT data;
// ...
auto it = data.find("dog");
if (it == data.end()) {
  // don't have such a key
}
auto position = distance(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Unfortunately, that's not the best way to do that, because distance function works in O(n) time for bidirectional iterators. Again, that's because of tree structure inside the std::map.